# What does it mean to be in a "complete" muddle?

Tags: meaning, idioms

People talk of *a complete mess*, *a complete failure*, *a complete success*, *a complete misunderstanding*...etc.

What do they mean by *complete*? In what sense can a failure, a sense of inferiority, a swindle, etc., indeed, anything other than things like jig-saw puzzles which have a specific number of pieces, be said to be *complete*?

Comment: Don't most people go through life in a partial muddle?

Comment: @HotLicks but oddly you don't hear of anyone being in a *partial muddle*. Usually they are in a *complete muddle*.

Comment: Well, actually, there's no need to say you're in a partial muddle because everyone already knows that.

Comment: The jigsaw reference is interesting. There are two meanings to the phrase "the jigsaw puzzle is complete": (a) there are no pieces missing, and (b) the puzzle has been solved. In this context, *complete* is akin to *perfect*: describing something that has reached a limit, or apogee of sorts. A "complete muddle" could not be any more muddled.

Comment: (An amazing number of questions here are the result of the confusion between English and mathematics.  Words like "complete", "absolute", "total", "almost", "half", et al, are not rigorously defined in terms of expressing a numerical degree or percentage of something, but rather express a sort of socially agreed-on level of severity, one that can vary considerably from one context to the next.  This allows a relatively small number of words to cover a broad range of concepts and contexts, and rarely with a significant loss of critical preciseness.)

Comment: @JHCL yes. One particular sense of *complete* is 17th century form - *the complete gentleman*, *the complete sportsman*. see OED sense 5a *Of persons: Fully equipped or endowed; perfect, accomplished, consummate; esp. in reference to a particular art or pursuit, as a complete actor, horseman, merchant. Now arch*. However the sense has been revived, and the 17th century spelling employed - *compleat*. A pub & restaurant in Marlow, by the River Thames, is known as *The Compleat Angler*. But I digress - my original question remains..

Comment: Well, I'm a bit muddled. I do not feel utterly confused or a total mess. Just slightly off-kilter. I guess things could be somewhat better.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Why should things have to have a specific number of pieces to be complete? What does that have to do with anything? Obviously, _complete_ has quite a few different meanings, but I don't see what your beef is, nor even quite with which meaning(s).

Comment: Well, "complete" is half a merism, as in "a complete and utter disregard for the rules of the game," for example.

Comment: @rhetorician - Which of course will produce the protestation that it's "redundant".

Answer (score 5):

I think it is used with the following meaning,

***[complete](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/complete):***

> - Absolute; thorough: *complete control; a complete mystery.*

(AHD)

***Complete:***

> - Of an action, state, or quality: Realized in its full extent; entire, thorough.

Early usage
examples:

> - ***1645 Ord. Lords & Com., Susp. fr. Sacram. 1*** Sincerely to endeavour the compleat establishment of Purity and Unity.
> - ***1663 Gerbier Counsel 19*** A man of compleat stature.
> - ***1727 De Foe Syst. Magic i. iv. (1840) 115*** The greatest and best principles are often illustrated..by their completest contraries.

(OED)

Comment: Surely not *absolute*? How could an inferiority complex be *absolute*? But people say *he has a complete inferiority complex*. Or how could a work of art be *an absolute masterpiece*?

Comment: A complete (by extension, total) inferiority complex.

Comment: @WS2 People say “complete inferiority complex”? As in, he doesn't just have a partial inferiority complex, but a whole one? That sounds utterly bizarre to me. “An absolute masterpiece”, on the other hand, sounds perfectly normal and straightforward to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Perhaps I did not chose a good example, but one certainly hears of *a complete idiot*.

Answer (score 4):

Wiktionary has a distinct (not listed in Oxford Online Dictionary or Merriam-Webster) definition of the word [***complete***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complete) as follows:

> *Generic intensifier*.
>
> - He is a complete bastard!‎
> - It was a complete shock when he turned up on my doorstep.‎
> - Our vacation was a complete disaster.‎

Sometimes, it could be replaced by other words, as [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complete) lists:

> - A complete renovation (thorough)
> - A complete silence (total or absolute)
> - A complete artist (highly proficient)

You could consider *complete* as a ***generic intensifier*** in your example.

Comment: Yes, in that phrase (cliche) 'complete' is generally an intensifier. Regionally, 'perfect muddle' (for example) has the same force.

Answer (score 1):

Failure means a lack of success.  Success sometimes means more then one thing.

If I'm attempting to make breakfast consisting of milk, toast, and bacon then I fail if I burn the toast.  But it's a complete failure if on top of the burnt toast the milk is curdled and the bacon is racid.

So a complete muddle must muddle in every possible way there is to muddle.

Otherwise your muddle is a bit muddled.

P.S. if you use 'complete' as simply a generic intensifier and are ignoring parts that are not in the state you claim (failed, muddled, etc) then I say it's actually incomplete and you are engaging in hyperbole.  But that's because I'm a complete git.